# Conditional \addlegendentry

Tags: pgfplots, conditionals

How can I add legend entries dependent on some variable? At least it does not work in the minimal example below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\def\myLegend{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Cost,
    ylabel=Error]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
      (2,-2.8559703)
      (3,-3.5301677)
      (4,-4.3050655)
      (5,-5.1413136)
      (6,-6.0322865)
      (7,-6.9675052)
      (8,-7.9377747)
    };
    \if\myLegend
    \addlegendentry{red line};
    \fi
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
\ifnum\myLegend>0
\addlegendentry{red line};
\fi
```

so nothing will be done when you have

```
\newcommand{\myLegend}{0}
```

while the legend will be seen if you have

```
\newcommand{\myLegend}{1}
```

Another approach is to have

```
\newif\ifmyLegend
```

in the preamble and

```
\ifmyLegend
\addlegendentry{red line};
\fi
```

in the body of the `tikzpicture`. You toggle with the declarations

```
\myLegendfalse
```

and

```
\myLegendtrue
```

The first is implicitly done by `\newif\ifmyLegend`.